# Jackson validate input json object

Tags: java, json, validation, jackson

I have a rest service and if I have a method for an example POST which consume application/json and the argument of the method is another class which describe the fields of the require json is there a way to make jackson to validate the input json before enter the method?
Here is a little code :

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public UserDataResourceObject login(UserResourceObject userResourceObject)
{
    Query query = getEm().createNamedQuery("User.authorize");
    if (userResourceObject == null)
    {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    query.setParameter("username", userResourceObject.getUsername());
    query.setParameter("password", Utility.getMD5Value(userResourceObject.getPassword()));
    Exception e = null;
    try
.................
```

And the UserResourceObject describe this structure :

```
{
  "username" : "admin",
  "password" : "123456"
}
```

I want if I change the structure of the json above jackson to throw me an exception for an example 400 (Bad request). How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org). And since you use Jackson, you can use [my implementation](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) to validate. This means however that you would need to receive the JSON directly into the method and map only if the schema finds it to be valid... I don't know of a means to do it before entering the method.

Comment: Thanks but I'm searching for other method for that.

Comment: Also I read somewhere that I can put a @Valid anotation before the parameter definition but it is not working,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  Bean Validation (JSR 303), to validate the data you receive.
You have http://bval.apache.org/ and http://hibernate.org/validator/ implementations.

Then you can do it that way:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public UserDataResourceObject login(@Valid UserResourceObject userResourceObject) {
```